# Multiple plots in python

Tags: python, plot

I want to plot a curve on an image. I would to see the curve only in a certain range. So:

```
plt.figure()
plt.imshow(img)
plt.plot(x, my_curve)
plt.axis([0, X, Y, 0])
```

But in this way also the image is showed in that range, but I don't want this. I would like to see the whole image with a portion of the curve. How can apply the axes only on the second plot?

Note that I can't use a slice of the arrays. I am in this situation:

```
x = [0 0 0 10 10 10 30 30 30 40 40 40]
my_curve = [0 0 0 10 10 10 30 30 30 40 40 40]
```

Well I need to see the straight line on the image, but only between pixels 25 and 35. If I delete each element out of such range, I obtain only the point (30,30) and I can not represent the straight line.

Answer (score 0):

If your data is sparse, you can interpolate it :

```
x2=np.linspace(x[0],x[-1],1000)[0:X]
my_curve2=np.interp(x2,x,my_curve)
plt.plot(x2, my_curve2)
```